# How do I count distinct and total users and logins by date range across two tables?

Tags: sql, count, case, distinct

I am trying to count users created in a month, let’s say January 2015.
Then I am trying to count users created as at January 31st, 2015.
Then I am trying to count distinct user IDs that logged in during a month, which would also be January 2015.
Then I am trying to count the total logins belonging to the distinct user IDs that logged in during January 2015.

The data is stored in 2 tables – users and auditlogins.  The primary key for both the users and auditlogins table is userid.

If I wrote each query separately, I would have the following queries:

```
SELECT 'Jan 2015' AS 'Month',
COUNT(users.userid) AS 'Total at month end' 
FROM users
WHERE users.datecreated < ('2015-02-01 00:00:00.000') 

SELECT 'Jan 2015' AS 'Month',
COUNT(users.userid)  AS 'User IDs created in Month'
FROM users
WHERE users.datecreated > ('2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND users.datecreated < ('2015-02-01 00:00:00.000') 

SELECT 'Jan 2015' AS 'Month',       
COUNT(DISTINCT auditlogins.userid) AS 'Unique User Logins in Month'
FROM auditlogins
WHERE auditlogins.logintime > ('2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND auditlogins.logintime < ('2015-02-01 00:00:00.000')

SELECT 'Jan 2015' AS 'Month',       
COUNT(auditlogins.userid) AS 'Total Logins in Month'
FROM auditlogins
WHERE auditlogins.logintime > ('2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND auditlogins.logintime < ('2015-02-01 00:00:00.000')
```

What I really want is everything in one row.  My final output would look like this:

Month   Total at month end  User IDs created in Month   Unique User Logins in Month Total Logins in Month
Jan-15  19,908  1,647   4,127   24,881

How do I do this?  I have tried CASE WHEN and joining the tables, but I cannot seem to get a distinct count of userids logging on within a date range.

Your help is greatly appreciated as this is frustrating me to no end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using COUNT(DISTINCT) and SUM with case statements.

```
DECLARE @MonthEnd DATE = '1/31/2015', @MonthDesc VARCHAR(50) = 'Jan 2015'
SELECT
    @MonthDesc AS [Month],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN users.datecreated < @MonthEnd THEN users.userid ELSE NULL END) AS [Total at month end],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(users.datecreated) = MONTH(@MonthEnd)
        AND YEAR(users.datecreated) = YEAR(@MonthEnd) THEN users.userid ELSE NULL END) AS [User IDs created in Month],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(logins.logintime) = MONTH(@MonthEnd)
        AND YEAR(logins.logintime) = YEAR(@MonthEnd) THEN users.userid ELSE NULL END) AS [Unique User Logins in Month],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(logins.logintime) = MONTH(@MonthEnd)
        AND YEAR(logins.logintime) = YEAR(@MonthEnd) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Logins in Month]
FROM users users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN auditlogins logins
        ON users.userid = logins.userid
```

Here is the query applied to sample data:

```
DECLARE @users TABLE (
    userid INT,
    datecreated DATETIME
)
DECLARE @auditlogins TABLE (
    userid INT,
    logintime DATETIME
)
INSERT @users VALUES (1, '1/1/2015'), (2, '12/1/2014')
INSERT @auditlogins VALUES (1, '1/1/2015'), (1, '1/15/2015'), (1, '2/1/2015'), (2, '1/15/2015')

DECLARE @MonthEnd DATE = '1/31/2015', @MonthDesc VARCHAR(50) = 'Jan 2015'
SELECT
    @MonthDesc AS [Month],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN users.datecreated < @MonthEnd THEN users.userid ELSE NULL END) AS [Total at month end],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(users.datecreated) = MONTH(@MonthEnd)
        AND YEAR(users.datecreated) = YEAR(@MonthEnd) THEN users.userid ELSE NULL END) AS [User IDs created in Month],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(logins.logintime) = MONTH(@MonthEnd)
        AND YEAR(logins.logintime) = YEAR(@MonthEnd) THEN users.userid ELSE NULL END) AS [Unique User Logins in Month],
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(logins.logintime) = MONTH(@MonthEnd)
        AND YEAR(logins.logintime) = YEAR(@MonthEnd) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Logins in Month]
FROM @users users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @auditlogins logins
        ON users.userid = logins.userid
```

This yields output:

```
Month      Total at month end User IDs created in Month Unique User Logins in Month Total Logins in Month
---------- ------------------ ------------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------
Jan 2015   2                  1                         2                           3
```

Comment: Hi Jason - thanks so much!  I knew my expected values, so when I read and ran your query, I was thrilled when the numbers matched perfectly.  I added a few more conditions for the users counts and all is great.  Now I need to apply this new COUNT(DISTINCT CASE knowledge to other areas of the system I am analyzing.